# How to create an android application that support and run perfect all screen size mobile device and Tablets?

Tags: android, icons, android-screen-support

Here I develop one application which has menu screen with 8 icons on that screen, i have two sets of icon according to size.
1 set icon size is 197 * 253
2 set icon size is 184 * 236

when i run this app in Tablet is look very nice, but when i run this app in Phone it looks very odd, it not looks well.

Comment: In the iPhone, is it stretched, or are there letterbox bars?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I'll rephrase.  In the phone, is it stretched, or are there letterbox bars?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create different layout folder for Supporting Multiple Screens.

> ayout-small
>   layout-normal
>   layout-large

it better to refer [Multiple screen support in android.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)